# How can I take generate mean image of many 32x32 grayscale images in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I have array are which is 50000x32x32. arr[i] stores the i-th grayscale image.

I want to compute the mean image of these images. I tried the following code(I got this code from stack overflow itself). This code was actually meant for RGB images.

I know, these changes of mine have a lot of mistakes, Apologies.

```
import os, numpy, PIL
from PIL import Image

# Access all PNG files in directory
allfiles=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
imlist=arr
N=len(imlist)
# Assuming all images are the same size, get dimensions of first         image
w,h=Image.fromarray(imlist[0]).size


# Create a numpy array of floats to store the average (assume RGB images)
brr=numpy.zeros((h,w),numpy.float)

# Build up average pixel intensities, casting each image as an array     of floats
for im in imlist:
    imarr=numpy.array(Image.fromarray(im),dtype=numpy.float)
    brr=brr+imarr/N

# Round values in array and cast as 8-bit integer
brr=numpy.array(numpy.round(arr),dtype=numpy.uint8)

# Generate, save and preview final image
out=Image.fromarray(brr,mode="L")
out.save("Average.png")
out.show()
```

Comment: Actually, it is in my Machine learning assignment, I know it is a DIP question, this is first time I have got introduced to something from DIP

Comment: Tags have to do with the *content* of the question, *not* its context; i.e., the fact that you may need assistance with, say, a sorting algorithm to be subsequently used in a spaceship, does not qualify the question as being about `space-engineering`.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. Do you get an error? Is the result not what you expected? Can you please edit your question to clarify what you expected to happen and what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your 5000 × 32 × 32 array, you can compute the mean image by using `np.mean()` with `axis=0` (the first axis, which contains the collection of images). Let's make some random data:

```
import numpy as np
images = np.random.random((5000, 32, 32))
```

Now we can compute the mean image:

```
mean_image = images.mean(axis=0)
```

We can look at it with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(mean_image)
```

Which looks something like:

[image: A matplotlib plot of a 32x32 array]